# Sum of absolute differences of neighbour pairs in a given array java

Tags: java, sum

I need to write a program for some kind of keypad that would look like this if `d=15.
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14`

User input should be d(length of this keypad), n(how many buttens sbd presses, eg. `3)` and the three buttons, chosen by user eg. `4 7 2`.

Then, the program is supposed to calculate the length between all these input integers (in this case from 4 to 7 and then from 7 to 3, which is 7) and print the sum.

I've somehow managed to come to the point where the only thing i don't know how to do is how to actually sum all the pair differences and print it.

The code:

```
int d=sc.nextInt();    
int n=sc.nextInt();

 int arr[]=new int[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){//for reading array
    arr[i]=sc.nextInt();

    }

        int sum=0;
        int diff=0;

        for(int i=0;i<=arr.length-1;i++) {
            if(i<)
                diff = Math.abs(arr[i+1]-arr[i]);    
        }
        sum+=diff;
        System.out.println(sum);
```

but basically the only thing this does is return the difference between the last two values of the array.

How do i fix it?

Comment: please share the code you have already, options you've tried

Comment: i think this might be enough. it's basically everything but the class and method

Comment: that doesn't even compile and if you fix that then you'll get an error before the output.

Answer (score 1):

The thing you've missed was summing outside of the cycle, you need to do that inside of the cycle as you'd like that to be done for each of the pairs you calculate difference for

```
for(int i=0;i<=arr.length-1;i++) {
    diff = Math.abs(arr[i+1]-arr[i]);   
    sum+=diff; // you need to move this into the cycle
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!